# Declaring the ROOT folder when running HTML site locally

Tags: html, url, browser, root, relative-path

I have a simple static site, with HTML pages in different directories and often run the site locally by opening a file in a browser.

The problem I'm having, is the browser doesn't recognize which folder is the ROOT, so any relative url that points back to the root folder (href="/about.html") won't function.

For example.

I open this in the browser: **file:///X:/DOCS/MySite/Directory1/page.html**

In this "page.html" I have this link: **href="/about.html"**

I want the link to point to: **file:///X:/DOCS/MySite/about.html**

But instead, it points to: **file:///about.html**

My question is: how do I tell the browser which folder is the ROOT?...or...is there another way to better run my site locally?

Note: Until now, I have been using lots of up-directory ("../") in my linking structure as a work around, but this is complicated and causing other issues, so being able to link based on the root ("/") would be far easier.

Comment: If you have one template for your surrounding html you could think over using [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score -1):

You can work around it with jQuery/JavaScript.

```
$("[href^='root:']").each(function() {
  var newRoot = "http://google.com/";
  $(this).attr("href", newRoot+$(this).attr("href").substr(5))
  return false;
});
```

This changes all links begining with `root:` so that with the code above, `href="root:index.html"` would turn into `href="http://google.com/index.html"`

However, this would not be applied with any links you are adding to the page later on using JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/ptarun/5rztY/1/

Comment: That would require to add `root:` before each link for developement and needs to be removed in production code, so what would be the benefit compared to make the links absolute to the local path in development code?

Comment: @t.niese Yes. I had assumed that you might not want all links to be changed as some may be external links. I thought detecting whether or not the link is external or not in any other way would be too much effort for something that could be removed by using *"Find root: and Replace with /"* in any old text editor.

Comment: @t.niese I don't understand why there would be any negative implications of using `root:` even in production code because you are changing it with JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Because it would only work if javascript is active and would prevent search-engines from indexing the site?